# jQuery adding css properties to element too soon

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to have an element on the page fade out upon mouseleave, then apply some css properties to it. The problem is that the css properties are being added to the element before it has completely faded out. Here is what I've tried:

```
$(".tiptrigger").mouseleave(function() { 
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("fast");

    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).css({"margin-left": "0px", "margin-top": "0px"});

});
```

When that didn't work, I tried:

```
$(".tiptrigger").mouseleave(function() { 
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id');

    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("fast").delay(500).css({"margin-left": "0px", "margin-top": "0px"});

});
```

And when that didn't work, I finally tried:

```
$(".tiptrigger").mouseleave(function() { 
    var s_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("fast");

}, function() {
    $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).css({"margin-left": "0px", "margin-top": "0px"});

});
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`callback function`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/#callback-function) here like:

```
$("#tiptip_holder-" + s_id).fadeOut("fast", function () {
    $(this).css({
        "margin-left": "0px",
        "margin-top": "0px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback:

```
$("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("fast", function(){
    $(this).css({"margin-left": "0px", "margin-top": "0px"});
});
```

This will complete the animation and, once that's completed, initiate whatever's in the callback (anonymous) function.

Using the `delay()` will only delay the animation queue.

References:

- [`fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$.when($("#tiptip_holder-" + s_id).fadeOut(500))
                               .done(function() {
    $(this).css({
        "margin-left": "0px",
        "margin-top": "0px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it as a callback function:

```
 $("#tiptip_holder-"+s_id).fadeOut("fast", function(){
        $(this).css({"margin-left": "0px", "margin-top": "0px"});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback on the fadeOut, to do something when the animation completes, like so:

```
$(".inner").mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut(400, function() {
        $(this).css({
            "margin-top": "0px",
            "margin-bottom": "0px"
        });
    });
});
```

Have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3GTrV/1/)